# Manually activate Network Manager Applet

Tags: network-manager

The issue I've is that when I connect via modem through gnome-ppp the Network Manager Applet don't detect a connection and don't let me use the configured VPNs via its interface.

How Can I manually activate the Network Manager Applet?

What I need is to enable the Network Manager apple in order to use the "VPN Connection" section of the GUI.

When I don't have an ethernet cable connected and I connect through a modem the Network Manager applet doesn't enables itself, it is like if don't recognizes the ppp0 interface. My question is: there is a way to force the Network Manager GUI indicator to make it "alive"/"up"/"enabled" in order to use the "VPN Connections"section?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with manually?
nm-applet (NetworkManager) is not intended for command-line nteraction but instead runs in the GNOME desktop environment.

Comment: @pl1nk: Hi! Thanks for take time to answer. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution for my own but it is a tricky one and it isn't useful for the people that don't have a Wireless adaptor.

The steps what I did were:

1. Enable the Wireless adaptor of my laptop by turning on the hardware switch.
2. Create a new ad-hoc connection.
3. Connect to the local wireless ad-hoc connection.
4. The Network-Manager applet brings to live allowing us to select the VPN to connect through.

Answer (score 1):

Run `nm-applet`.  Make sure you have a panel running.
If you need command-line interaction capability, check out wicd and wicd-curses.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I executed `nm-applet` and it showed up two Network Manager indicators instead of "activate it".

Answer (score 0):

For testing run as root `nm-applet` and check if ppp0 is activated.

In any case check files:

`/etc/dbus-1/system.d/NetworkManager.conf`

`/etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-applet.conf`

And alter them according to your needs.
This [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877692) may be of help to you.